# MUI Textfield Label is within the textfield value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

When I want to create an input, I saw that the input value and the label were both inside the input value.
The initial value is from an Axios call

```
    <TextField
              fullWidth
              label="Name"
              name="name"
              variant="outlined"
              value={formik.values.name}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={formik.touched.name && Boolean(formik.errors.name)}
              helperText={formik.touched.name && formik.errors.name}
            />
```

[image: When is not focused]

Comment: Add `InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}`

Comment: Does not work @GaneshMB